# Two vertical scrollbars in IE

Tags: html, css

I've created a page at **http://gregcoltman.com/greg_template_01/index4.html** which works exactly as I want it on Firefox and Chrome but in Internet Explorer there are two vertical scrollbars and the page doesn't display correctly.
I'd really appreciate some help on this please.

Comment: Fixing a page rendering in IE can be a time consuming and annoying process. As it looks like you are using a fair amount of CSS that may be incompatible with IE < 10 I would recommend looking into CSSPIE, a helper that can render the stuff that is hard for IE. http://css3pie.com/

Comment: You might also consider using the `modernizr` library.

Comment: It looks fine in IE10 btw

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies! I will look into these options :)